# Singleton in a Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, singleton

Can i use a singleton within a servlet to share information between diffrent session.

I know that only 1 instance Servlet is running at any time. Calling service method for each incoming request. But how about creating another Singleton class (for eg: ShareSingleton) which calls its getInstance() in the servlets Init() method. This ShareSingleton can carry data that needs to be shared between sessions/reqests.

Is it risky to use such an approach in servlets ?

Comment: Did it work when you tried it? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: The servlet context is maybe a better place to put shared information. See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: It works. I am only worried about the consistency of this approach

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First..see this for the best approach of singletons: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/07/why-enum-singleton-are-better-in-java.html

Second: Remember singletons are only single to the JVM. So..if you have more than one JVM running do not expect each singleton to have the same state.

Third: To be safe, I would instantiate the singleton from a listener of the servlet context.

see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html

define a class in your web.xml and instantiate it there. Your singleton will be created when your webapp starts up rather than when n people hit the service method of your servlet at once.

Comment: Thanks. 1. I am using enum singleton. 2. This is exactly why i do not want to use ApplicationContext. I need to store info per JVM also (for a cluster applicaiton)

Comment: I may add. Instantiating a Singleton within the init of a servlet is ok...in this case. It will be already defined in the web.xml and will be instantiated when your server comes up.

However...this isn't the best. Like I said. If you have a load balancer that is filtering traffic between 10 JVMs. Who knows what the singleton on JVM n holds..

Comment: So you're using Spring? Does the singleton hold state?

Comment: Sorry. I just read your reply again...I answered my own question. What info are you holding in this singleton and why can you not achieve it through config?

Comment: I am using this to hold some ManagedServer stats like load/noofrequests served per JVM/ManagedServer.

Comment: Does your load balancer not tell you those stats? Seems like your reinventing the wheel...i dont mean to insult.

If you want / need to implement your own way then the above is fine..you'll get JVM specific results..which is what you want.

Comment: If you can afford it I'd suggest looking at newrelic or appdynamics. I've personally used both. Both are very good tools.

Comment: Both hold JMX stats like you want

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Note that the servlet container may use multiple instance of the Servlet object, so you'll have to make sure one object is shared amongst all these instances.

For example, you might do:

```
private static final Cache<String,String> = //cache
```

And then use the value in the cache if it's available, or otherwise update the cache with a newly calculated value. Note that the object that is shared must be thread safe.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're saying here? "Note that the servlet container may use multiple instance of the Servlet object"? Servlets are only created once to handle requests. Do you mean JVMs?

Comment: Enno is right. You can declare the same servlet class twice in web.xml with different names, some containers may create pool of servlet instances.

Comment: Interesting. You learn something every day. Could you elaborate on the containers that do?

Comment: Looks like the spec specifies that it wouldn't, unless the SingleThreadModel is implemented (which is deprecated). Not sure why I thought it will routinely do that... @Slihp